# How to copy my files from one directory to another directory?

Tags: android, file, directory

I am working on Android. My requirement is that I have one directory with some files, later I downloaded some other files into another directory and my intention is to copy all the files from latest directory into first directory. And before copying the files into first directory from latest I need to remove all files from the first directory.

Answer (score 23):

```
    void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
       FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
       FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
       try {
          inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
       } finally {
          if (inChannel != null)
             inChannel.close();
          if (outChannel != null)
             outChannel.close();
       }
    }
```

I can't remember where I found this, but it was from a useful article I used to backup a SQLite database.

Comment: Just simple and perfect. Don't know if will works fine with big files, just in case, let to test it.

Comment: This will move the database. if your app is running, it will give you SQLDatabasenot found error, as soon as this code run.
you can just add
** FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);(both are file  )**

Comment: not working well for me. I find the copied files with zero bytes.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use also below code:

```
public static void copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation)
        throws IOException {

    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        if (!targetLocation.exists()) {
            targetLocation.mkdir();
        }

        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceLocation.listFiles().length; i++) {

            copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                    new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
        }
    } else {

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

        // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you write this codes for returning a boolean value ?