# changing byte when copy file not working

Tags: android

changing byte when copy file form one location to another not working whats wrong in my code please help me if i remove string s1; then its work perfect just duplicate original file when i alter bytes using s1 string its not work

```
 samplet.text file contain numbers


            3434214280
            3044559080
             3154356865
          3312430124
         3334491537
                 package com.example.copyfilefromdirectorytoanother;


   ublic class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity.java";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // your sd card
    String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    // the file to be moved or copied
    File sourceLocation = new File (sdCard + "/sample.txt");

    // make sure your target location folder exists!
    File targetLocation = new File (sdCard + "/MyNewFolder/sample.txt");

    // just to take note of the location sources
    Log.v(TAG, "sourceLocation: " + sourceLocation);
    Log.v(TAG, "targetLocation: " + targetLocation);

    try {

        // 1 = move the file, 2 = copy the file
        int actionChoice = 2;

        // moving the file to another directory
        if(actionChoice==1){

            if(sourceLocation.renameTo(targetLocation)){
                Log.v(TAG, "Move file successful.");
            }else{
                Log.v(TAG, "Move file failed.");
            }

        }

        // we will copy the file
        else{

            // make sure the target file exists

            if(sourceLocation.exists()){

                InputStream in = new 
 FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
                OutputStream out = new 
    FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

                // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
                String s1;
            //  byte[] theByteArray ;
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                byte[] theByteArray = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                int n =1;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {


s1= "BEGIN:VCARD \n VERSION:2.1 \n N:;UNKNOWN "+n+";;; \n FN:UNKNOWN "+n+" 
 \n TEL;CELL;PREF:+92"+buf+" \n     END:VCARD ";
                    theByteArray=s1.getBytes();

                    out.write(theByteArray, 0, len);
                    n=n+1;
                }

                in.close();
                out.close();

                Log.v(TAG, "Copy file successful.");

            }else{
                Log.v(TAG, "Copy file failed. Source file 
       missing.");
            }

        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're reading in len bytes, appending data to it, then writing out len bytes.  That's wrong, you need to do `out.write(theByteArray, 0, theByteArray.length);`   I can see other possible problems there too, but your file may be small enough to avoid them.